# Advantage of Google Mail App

Tags: gmail, google-chrome

What is the point of the [Google Mail app by Google on the Web App Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia?hl=en-US#)? by default it opens in a normal tab, has the address bar etc visible and is basically just a big bookmark on the new tab page. Or am I missing something?

What advantage is there to using a web app than just have a bookmark on the bookmark bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no advantages, it's essentially just a link.

Mainly it's so you have your mail link with the other apps you use in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine they will be incorporating their current and in-development webapps-becoming-more-like-desktop-apps features, such as the background feature:

http://blog.chromium.org/2011/02/amping-up-chromes-background-feature.html

> Apps and extensions that use the new “background” feature can continue to run in the background—even if the user closes down all of Chrome’s windows. “Background apps” will continue to run until Chrome exits. The next time Chrome starts up, any background windows that were previously running will also be re-launched. These windows are not going to be visible but they will be able to perform tasks like checking for server-side changes and pre-emptively loading content into local storage.

Answer (score 0):

On Chromebooks, these links can be pinned to the taskbar and show up as open in the taskbar.